# JQuery Mobile Popup did not show up

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

Im using JQueryMobile 1.2.0.

I want to show popup programmatically, so I have the following:

```
$('#btn').on('click',function(){
    alert('this is ok');
    $('#popupBasic').popup();

});
```

In a JQM page:

```
<div data-role="popup" id="popupBasic">
    <p>This is a completely basic popup, no options set.<p>
</div>
```

But the popup did not show up. Any fix on this? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Opening a popup in jQueryMobile requires you to either

1. Call the `open` method with `$('#popupBasic').popup("open");`
2. Simply navigate to it with an hyperlink such as `<a href="#popupBasic" data-rel="popup" data-transition="slidedown" >Slide down the popup</a>`

Answer (score 2):

Here's an working example: http://jsfiddle.net/Gajotres/YMXgv/

```
<a href="#" data-transition="none" data-role="button" data-inline="true" data-rel="popup" id="testButton">Popup example</a>  


$('#testButton').bind('click', function(e) {
    $("#popupBasic").popup("open")
});
```